# SQLException during Scada-LTS startup

Tags: mysql, jdbc, scada, scadalts

When starting Scada-LTS (open source, web-based SCADA software) on Linux (ubuntu)  I'm getting following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:713)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:647)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:468)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:145)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:554)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:242)
at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:141)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:848)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:836)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1110)
at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:689)
at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:273)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5522)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1092)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1984)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
    ... 32 more
```

Apparently there is some configuration problem. Any hint highly appreciated.